# SFTP for users (own site folder)

Tags: shell, sftp, centos7

I'm trying to config SFTP, so that my users can access their own site folder (with PSFTP/FileZilla). I use Vagrant, CentOS7, NGINX and .sh file.

This is my bootstrap.sh, for creating one of my users.

```
#Make Group for SFTP
sudo groupadd sftpusers
#Make Website folder and SFTP Users
JS_WWW="/usr/share/nginx/html/jeroensteen"
sudo useradd -g sftpusers -d $JS_WWW -s /sbin/nologin -p jeroensteen jeroensteen
sudo chown jeroensteen:sftpusers $JS_WWW
sudo chown nginx:nginx $JS_WWW

#Configure SFTP
sudo sed -i "s@/usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server@internal-sftp@" /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sudo echo "Match Group sftpusers" > /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sudo echo " ChrootDirectory /usr/share/nginx/html/%u" > /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sudo echo " ForceCommand internal-sftp" > /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sudo systemctl restart sshd
```

When I try to do normal SSH with Putty with user "vagrant" on 127.0.0.1, putty closes. I can't even enter a password.

When I try to SFTP, with PSFTP by doing "open 10.0.0.100": I login as "jeroensteen@10.0.0.100" with my pass, but I get: "Access denied".

How can I config SFTP for my users? What is going wrong that Putty closes and I don't have access?

Answer (score 0):

You should run `sudo tail -f /var/log/secure` and try the sftp again while watching that. That will show you the errors from the sshd server that aren't allowing this sftp access.

From looking at the steps you performed, after you set the ownership of $JS_WWW to jeroensteen:sftpusers, you change it to nginx:nginx. Did you perhaps mean to set the user to jeroensteen and the group to nginx? Does the jeroensteen user have any access to the $JS_WWW directory? You never show what the permissions are. If the permissions aren't world-readable and world-executable, the login may be failing due to permissions issues on $JS_WWW. You can use `sudo su -s /bin/sh jeroensteen` to switch to that user and see what it can access.

Personally, when I'm trying to accomplish what you're doing, I leave the sshd_config alone and instead install [rssh](http://www.pizzashack.org/rssh/) from [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) and set the user's shell to that.